# Changed base url, website not working after

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2

I changed base url from magento and now backend/frontend isnt working almost at all.
I can get to the page where i can change it back but "save config" button does nothing saying "Refused to apply style from 'https://www.audiocity.ee/electronics-home/?___store=default/media/css_secure/3b139e1b7b1c24f568e33943a188f95e.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

Any ideas if its possible to fix without ftp/server access

I have no FTP or server access.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the database, try changing it back in the database. It is definitely not the recommended approach but since you don't have access to the server, this seems like the only approach to me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: By database you mean FTP server? I only have access to magento.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is working `https://www.audiocity.ee/`, log into admin then flush the cache and reindex all to solve the other pages.

[image]

Comment: Only the front page works, click on banner and it goes wrong.
The problem is that i cant get into admin properly.

Some categories work as well but products re-direct to https://www.audiocity.ee/electronics-home/?___store=default/

In admin i can get to the place where i change base url but save button doesnt work.
https://imgur.com/U8ASPP1 - pic of admin side

Comment: If you haven't server access, there no miracle solition

Comment: Okay, gotta wait till monday then.

Thank you for the help anyways :)